# How can i run software created for windows ce into window tab?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-ce

Hi I have developed on software using visual basic for windows CE, now i want to run the same software on windows TAB. how can i do that....pls help
I tried directly running software into my windows based tab. it shows some error.

Answer (score 0):

If TAB means tablet and it runs any version of Windows (8,10 etc.) that is not CE then your application will not run as it is.
Posting the error message you get would help.
But if the app has been designed for the .NET Compact Framework, at least you need to take the source code and rebuild it for the full .NET Framework. Some things may not compatible and you may need to fix or change parts of your code. Estimating this is not simple and depends on the features used by your application.

Answer (score 0):

Well you may not like this solution, but you could run a windows mobile or windows CE emulator inside of full blown windows (windows 7, 8.1 or 10).  Then install and run your application on the emulator.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16182